# How to retrieve data from specific node from firebase in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve phonenumbers joined under CircleMembers of current user but datasnapshot returning null.Please help me out.Which is proper way to retrieve members under mycircle.

My firebase database is below
[image: my firebase]

Here is my code.

```
 
   userReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child( "Users" );
       databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child( "Users").child( user.getUid() ).child( "CircleMembers" );
     databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent( new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
```

nameList.clear();

            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                for(DataSnapshot  dss:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    String circlememberID = dss.child( "CircleMembers" ).getValue(String.class);
                    userReference.child( circlememberID )
                            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent( new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                                    phone = dataSnapshot.getValue( Phone.class );
                                    //fetching phone numbers under Circlemembers (to which circle current user is joined)
                                    nameList.add( phone);
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                                }
                            } );

                    adapter = new MembersAdaptor(nameList,getApplicationContext());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter( adapter );
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }

            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "No circle", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    } );

Comment: Please add relevant code that you've tried.. Secondly, is the phone number that you want to get the same phone number on the first node; that is, the phone numbers  directly under the Users node?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add some codes of what you have tried.

Comment: Hello and welcome on StackOverflow!!! In order to get your a better answer, and your answer don't get deleted later on, you would have to read and follow some basic rules and conventions that will help everyone to communicate and help better. Please go to https://stackoverflow.com/help and read about the topic "What topics can I ask about here?", and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?".

Comment: @DominicOrim I want to get phone numbers which are listed under "CircleMembers" of current user(i.e. list of phone numbers).I am new. Plz guide me

Comment: Help us understand your node structure.. After the `Users` node, what is the next node? And if we want to get the value of that node programmatically, how can we get it (I mean, you can get the userUid by user.getUid(), and I believe the next node under `Users` is a phone number,) so how can we get the value of the node under `Users`; in other words, how can we get the phone number of that particular user programatically?

Comment: @jiya Have you solved the issue? Please responde with @.

Comment: @DominicOrim Thanks for replying.I have replaced current users's uid with current user's phonenumber but still not working.    
   FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child( user.getPhoneNumber() ).child("CircleMembers");              Is this right way to access CircleMembers of current user??

Comment: @AlexMamo not yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all those phone numbers that exist under the `CircleMemebers` node, please use the following code:

```
String phoneNo = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getPhoneNumber();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference circleMemebersRef = rootRef.child("Users").child(phoneNo).child("CircleMemebers");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String phoneNumber = ds.getValue(String.class);
            Log.d(TAG, phoneNumber);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
    }
};
circleMemebersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in your logcat will be:

```
+919212143422
+615325453454
```

Comment: Its working but it showing output like pudATsl6Cxfb42Ks5o5OZbSg5no1: 
"+919212143422" So how to extract only phone number??I dont want to display userID.

Comment: I want to display only list of phone numbers.Please tell me how to extract that.

Comment: It should only display de phone number. Have you used the exact code I have provided you?

Comment: Sorry alex it was my mistake I did String circleMembers = cSnapshot.getValue().toString()  but its fine now I changed it  to  String circleMembers = cSnapshot.getValue(String.class); And thank you so much alex..:)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a trial. I think this is the way your code should go:

```
userReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child( "Users");
//Changed databaseReference to userCircleMembersRef for easier understanding of nodes
userCircleMembersRef = 
    userReference .child( user.getPhoneNumber()).child( "CircleMembers" );

userCircleMembersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent( new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                   nameList.clear();
                   if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                  for(DataSnapshot  dss:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                   Phone phone = dss.child( user.getUid()).getValue( Phone.class );
                  //fetching phone numbers under Circlemembers (to which circle current user is joined)
                  nameList.add( phone);
    }
                        adapter = new MembersAdaptor(nameList,getApplicationContext());
                        recyclerView.setAdapter( adapter );
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();          
        }else{
             Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "No circle", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }
        }

        @Override
          public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
          Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    });
        }
```